# Assigning a pointer to an integer

Tags: c, pointers, assignment-operator

Can I assign a pointer to an integer variable? Like the following.

```
int *pointer;
int array1[25];
int addressOfArray;

pointer = &array1[0];

addressOfArray = pointer;
```

Is it possible to do like this?

Comment: have you given it a try?

Comment: What do you expect such an assignment to accomplish? Tell us what actual problem you're trying to solve, and we can help with that.

Comment: Unless you have a good reason for this, don't do it.  And if you do do it, don't use an `int`, since an `int` isn't necessary large enough to hold a pointer on all systems (e.g. the common [LP64 and LLP64 models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit#64-bit_data_models)).  Instead, use [`intptr_t`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#stdint.h).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not without an explicit cast, i.e.

```
addressOfArray = (int) pointer;
```

There's also this caveat:

> **6.3.2.3 Pointers**
> ...
> 6 Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the
> result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type,
> the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer
> type.

So the result isn't guaranteed to be a meaningful integer value.

Comment: Thanks for adding the caveat, I found (and was confused by) such code buried in a lua implementation.

Comment: Correct answer, but you could include the *reason* why the cast is necessary (the constraint on the assignment operator mentioned by @ouah).

Comment: Preferably, the type `uintptr_t` should be used instead of `int`, as it comes with a whole lot less implementation-defined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is no valid to assign a pointer to an integer. It's a constraint violation of the assignment operator (C99, 6.5.16.1p1). A compiler has the right to refuse to translate a program with a pointer to integer assignment.

Comment: You CAN do a cast, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

It's done frequently in embedded programming with some caveats:

- the operation (most likely) requires casting, and
- generally implies that you are working without an operating system or working very closely with the RTOS (i.e, driver-level development)

Comment: Is it? I have never done it, except when implementing pointer_to_string. However I have done integer(literal) to pointer quite a bit.

Comment: My ARM bsp does some magic during boot: "size = (unsigned)&__romend - (unsigned)&__romstart;"  I've seen this sort of thing frequently in bare-metal applications.

Comment: `extern int8_t *__romend; extern int8_t *__romstart; size_t size=__romend-__romstart;` If pointers are correct type you just have to subtract one from the other to get the some answer, as @Throwback1986.

Comment: Sure, there is more than one way to defur a feline.  Another example: my GreenHills RTOS permits message passing using Buffers (their Buffer does not mean a simple memory buffer).  To setup a Buffer, something like this is done:     
`bufferControl.BufferType = DataBuffer | LastBuffer;
 bufferControl.TheAddress = (Address)&msgControl;
 bufferControl.Length = MAX_VAS_MESSAGE_SIZE;
 bufferControl.Transferred = 0;`  Since `Address` is just a typedef for `unsigned long int`, a situation similar to OP's question is presented.

Comment: Yes that is the other time you need to do it, badly written libraries. But honesty (trust me I am a software engineer ), you don't need to do it. Unless you are implementing print_pointer. If you ever write a cast, then ask yourself at least 3 times if you have to, then ask 3 other people. Only then consider that it may be the best way to do it.

Comment: Interesting viewpoint.  Typecasts are hard to avoid when writing a  low-level driver, an RGB565 LCD driver immediately comes to mind. It's also helpful in SPI and I2C interfaces (particularly in assembling multi-byte data from a single-byte transaction).  In general, it's difficult to avoid casting when developing code that complies with MISRA-C 2004, successfully passes static code analysis (i.e. Coverity, CodeSonar, etc), and meets coding standard requirements.

Comment: I write drivers, dispatchers, schedulers, mmu configurers etc. I use pc-lint to staticly analyse my code, complying to misra. And I have people working for me that tell me it can't be done without casts. So I show them how to do it better without casts. `uint16_t assemble(int8_t lower, int8_t higher) {return (higher<<8) | lower;}` and see misca 11.3,

Comment: "the operation (most likely) requires casting" should be "the operation requires casting". This is required by the C language, period. As for MISRA-C, the rule about not casting from integers to pointers is advisory and has to be ignored in most embedded systems.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

You are attempting to assign a "pointer to int" value to an "int" variable. You will get a compiler warning for sure. You could do:

```
int *pointer;
int array1[25];
int *addressOfArray;

pointer = &array1[0];
//The following commented lines are equivalent to the pointer assignment above and are also valid
//pointer = array
//pointer = &array[0]

addressOfArray = pointer;
```

This is known as a shallow copy. If you are not already familiar with the concept, I highly recommend you read it (Google "deep vs shallow copying").

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
memcpy(&addressOfArray, &pointer, sizeof(int));
```

Which would directly copy the underlying bytes and supplant the casting operator, but I definitely wouldn't recommend it, unless you know for sure that `sizeof(int) == sizeof(int *)` on your system.

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, it's possible to convert a pointer to an `int` with a cast. Not recommended, but possible. And it might turn out bad.

But there are more integer types than just `int`. For example, we have `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` which are for this exact purpose.

So you can do this and it's 100% safe.

```
uintptr_t addressOfArray;
addressOfArray = (uintptr_t) pointer;
```

And then, if you really really want to (cannot see a reason why) you could do this:

```
int myInt;
if(addressOfArray <= INT_MAX) {
    myInt = addressOfArray;
} else {
```