# What is the rule for why this pointer value can't be converted to an integer?

Tags: c++, pointers, type-conversion

I just want to know what the rule is for why this isn't allowed, as the reason given to me isn't exactly clear.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float* pointer = new float;
    long long bigNumber = 1;
    int a = bigNumber; // Allowed
    short b = bigNumber // Allowed
    a = (int)pointer; // Not allowed
    a = (long long)pointer; // Allowed

    return 0;
}
```

The line that I've marked with "Not allowed" gives an error. In Visual Studio it says:

> 'type cast': cannot convert from 'float *' to 'int'

This is clear but doesn't explain why. However when I compile the code on onlinegdb online C++ compiler, I get the following error message for that line:

> error: cast from ‘float*’ to ‘int’ loses precision [-fpermissive]
>
> [link](https://onlinegdb.com/r1e-sXr57)

I've tried at Ideone, cppbuzz and jdoodle online compilers and I get the same message. So it's saying the reason is that it's not allowed because there is loss of precision. But when I assign a long long to an int or short that is also resulting in a loss of precision but it doesn't give me an error, which makes me think it's breaking another rule other than just that it's losing precision.

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489027/assigning-a-pointer-to-an-integer), wherein the top answer says that it's an impermissible conversion without the explicit cast, though note that this is a C, not C++ question. Indeed I get a different message if I don't explicitly cast the pointer to the int, I get instead:

> error: invalid conversion from ‘float*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]

With no mention of loss of precision.

If I set Visual Studio to 32bit, that line no longer gives an error, because a pointer size is 32 bit and so is an int in my case.

My question is what is the rule that prevents this? It can't just be a loss of precision issue as it allows loss of precision when assigning a long long to an int or short.

Comment: The rule is that the C++ Standard provides no implicit conversion from pointers to non-pointer types.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ standard allows a `reinterpret_cast` from a pointer type to an integral type only if the mapping is injective. It appears that on your implementation, `int` is not large enough (probably because `int` is 32-bit and pointers are 64-bit). Therefore the cast is not allowed.

Comment: I don't understand what injective mapping means, but I take it to mean the pointer type must be converted to an integer type of the same size, or that allows the same range of numbers as representable by the pointer type.

Comment: @zebrafish same size or larger.

Answer (score 1):

The gcc error is somewhat misleading, the conversion is not from **pointer value** to int but from pointer type to int, such implicit conversion is not allowed. pointer types are convertible to integral types large enough to holding them, (e.g `std::intptr_t`).